# How do you call a function in a react-table accessor? (reactjs)

Tags: reactjs, accessor, react-table

I am modifying a ReactJS component. I have added a react-table to get the pagination, which works beautifully.  But one of the columns in the table needs to call a function that is also in this component, so it can render a link depending on the content of that record.  (Some results will render a link, some will not.)  When I list the function in the accessor property of the column, it returns some of the values from the function, but not all of them.  So, the link comes back as:

```
    localhost:3000/view/c/IDnumber/undefined.
```

Both the IDnumber and query should be returned, but the query parameter is "undefined".

I've tried listing the function in the accessor like:

```
    getSerialNo(hit,query)
```

But then I get "hit is not defined".
I've searched on this site and others to find a solution.

The column looks like:

```
    {id:'serialno',
    Header: "Serial #",
    accessor: getSerialNo
    }
```

The function, in part, looks like:

```
    const getSerialNo = (hit, query) => {
        const linkAs = '/view/c/${hit._id}/${query}'
    return <Link href={link} as={linkAs}><a target="_blank">{serialNo}
     </a></Link>
```

I would like to get back a link that actually includes the query, like:

```
    localhost:3000/view/c/IDnumber/query
```

Comment: got the answer on another forum.  use: const myCustomAccessor = row => getSerialNo(row, props.tableHeader) and then in the accessor call:  accessor: myCustomAccessor

Answer (score 21):

according to documentation

> **accessor: String | Function**
>
> Required This string/function is used to
> build the data model for your column. The data returned by an accessor
> should be primitive and sortable. If a string is passed, the column's
> value will be looked up on the original row via that key, eg. If your
> column's accessor is firstName then its value would be read from
> row['firstName']. You can also specify deeply nested values with
> accessors like info.hobbies or even address[0].street If a function is
> passed, the column's value will be looked up on the original row using
> this accessor function, eg. If your column's accessor is row =>
> row.firstName, then its value would be determined by passing the row
> to this function and using the resulting value.

Its accept both string or function but make sure you set the id, you can do any operation on the row like `row.attrbuiteName === null ? "no thing" : row.attrbuiteName`

```
{
     id:'serialno',
     Header: "Serial #",
     accessor: row => row.attrbuiteName
     }
```

Reference:

https://github.com/tannerlinsley/react-table/blob/master/docs/api.md

**Note** in case using the function you must provide ***id*** in row

Comment: But search is not working if I add anchor tag or Link (react router dom). Any solution on this ?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, as mentioned above, you can call a function inside an accessor like so:

```
 {
    Header: 'Column header',
    accessor: (row) => {
      // some function that returns a primitive value you want to display in the cell
    },
  },
```

I'm adding an updated [link to documentation](https://react-table.tanstack.com/docs/api/useTable#column-options) as the one above does not seem to work anymore.